# How can I get the first word from each string in my Dataframe using Python?

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame called "data" with 2 columns and 50 rows filled with one or two  lines of text each, imported from a .tsv file. Some of the questions may contain integers and floats, besides strings. I am trying to extract the first word of every sentence (in both columns), but consistently get this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'.

At first, I thought the error was due to my wrong use of "data.str.split", but all changes I could Google failed. Then I through the file might not be composed of all strings. So I tried "data.astype(str)" on the file, but the same error remained. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
questions = "questions.tsv"
data = pd.read_csv(questions, usecols = [3], nrows = 50, header=1, sep="\t")
data = data.astype(str)
first_words = data.str.split(None, 1)[0]
```

Comment: Yes, both work! Thanks so much! Just to learn, any idea why my approach failed?

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't call `.str` accessor on a dataframe directly.

Comment: Thanks, very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
first_words = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.split().str[0])
```

Or:

```
first_words = data.applymap(lambda x: x.split()[0])
```

Sample:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':['aa ss ss','ee rre', 1, 'r'],
                   'b':[4,'rrt ee', 'ee www ee', 6]})
print (data)
          a          b
0  aa ss ss          4
1    ee rre     rrt ee
2         1  ee www ee
3         r          6

data = data.astype(str)
first_words = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.split().str[0])
print (first_words)
    a    b
0  aa    4
1  ee  rrt
2   1   ee
3   r    6
```

---

```
first_words = data.applymap(lambda x: x.split()[0])
print (first_words)
    a    b
0  aa    4
1  ee  rrt
2   1   ee
3   r    6
```

Comment: I could not understand what you said well, but from what I understood, it seemed like you were upset

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see `x.str.split().str[0]` in your answer.

Comment: Fantastic. So happy to see you thinking positively.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you attempted to use the `pd.Series.str` string accessor on a `pd.DataFrame`.  Unfortunately, it is a `pd.Series` only attribute.  That means you need to use it in a `pd.Series` context.  You can accomplish in several ways.

**Setup**
Assume your dataframe looked like this

```
              Col1               Col2
0   this is a test        hello world
1  this is another          pandas123
2            test3       tommy trojan
3         etcetera  one more sentence
```

---

**Option 1**
Use `stack` to convert a 2-dimensional dataframe into a series... then use the string accessor

```
#  Make a
#  Series
#  /----\    
df.stack().str.split(n=1).str[0].unstack()
#                                 \_____/
#                                 Turn it
#                                   Back

       Col1       Col2
0      this      hello
1      this  pandas123
2     test3      tommy
3  etcetera        one
```

---

**Option 2**
Or you can use `pd.DataFrame.apply` to use the `pd.Series.str` accessor on each column separately.
This is covered in @jezrael's answer.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(n=1).str[0])

       Col1       Col2
0      this      hello
1      this  pandas123
2     test3      tommy
3  etcetera        one
```

---

**Option 3**
Use a comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame({c: df[c].str.split(n=1).str[0] for c in df})

       Col1       Col2
0      this      hello
1      this  pandas123
2     test3      tommy
3  etcetera        one
```

---

You'll notice that in all options, we used the `str` on a `pd.Series` object and not a `pd.DataFrame` object.

Comment: Awesome! I think `split(n=1)` might improve efficiency a bit, because splitting stops after the first word (everything after is unnecessary). This was covered in my (now deleted) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231815/4909087).

Comment: Added. Thanks for tip.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I am a starter, so I am grateful for this steep learning curve!